# Add Pre default text in phalcon flash messages

Tags: phalcon, phalconeye

In phalcon default flash messaging service only provide with default error div.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning">Our message</div>
```

But i want to add something inside div box like this.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning"> <button class="close">x</button> Our Message </div>
```

However, phalcon we are only allow to set only class of each message as per my knowledge.

```
$di->set('flash', function () {
    return new FlashSession([
        'error'   => 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible',
        'notice'  => 'alert alert-info alert-dismissible',
        'warning' => 'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible'
    ]);
});
```

Is there any configuration or any other way to add that close button on every message. I want something like

```
message = '<button class="close-btn">x</button>'+message
```

However i don't want to add this close button on every flash message because in future may be i need to change the class of close button so that in that case i need to change in all from the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending the Phalcon\FlashSession class and overriding the outputMessage() method, or by creating your own flash component to output the HTML you desire. Example of a custom flash component is below, we use a similar class when we develop with Falcon, this component assumes the existence of a session component in the DI.

This is untested but the code in principle would give you the ability to add a close button to the output HTML, or you can set specific HTML content for each message type in the relevant methods (error, success, warning, info).

Example usage:

```
// settings messages in your controllers / components
// 2nd param defines a position
$this->flashMessage->error('Something is bad!', 'form_top');
$this->flashMessage->success('Something is right!');
$this->flashMessage->info('Something is interesting!');
$this->flashMessage->warning('Something is worrying!');

// rendering messages in your views
// 1st param will render messages for a specific position if a position was set
$this->flashMessage->render();
$this->flashMessage->render('form_top');
```

Example class:

```
class FlashMessage extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{    
    /**
     * @var array
     **/
    public $classmap = array();

    /**
     * Sets defaults for the class map (optional)
     *
     * @param array $classmap
     **/
    public function __construct($classmap = array()) {

        // -- set the defaults 
        $this->classmap = array(
            'error'   => 'flash_message-error',
            'success' => 'flash_message-success',
            'info'  => 'flash_message-info',
            'warning' => 'flash_message-warning'
        );

        // -- set new class map options (also optional)
        if (!empty($classmap)) {
            foreach ($classmap as $key => $value) {
                $this->classmap[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * error(), success(), info(), warning()
     * Sets the flash messages
     *
     * @param  string message
     * @param  string position
     * @return string
     **/
    public function error($message, $position = '')
    {
        $this->session->flashMessage = array(
            'position' => $position, 
            'message' => '<div class="' . $this->classmap['error'] . '">
                 ' . $message . '
             </div>
        ');
    }

    public function success($message, $position = '')
    {
        $this->session->flashMessage = array(
            'position' => $position, 
            'message' => '<div class="' . $this->classmap['success'] . '">
                 ' . $message . '
             </div>
        ');
    }

    public function info($message, $position = '')
    {
        $this->session->flashMessage = array(
            'position' => $position, 
            'message' => '<div class="' . $this->classmap['info'] . '">
                 ' . $message . '
             </div>
        ');
    }

    public function warning($message, $position = '')
    {
        $this->session->flashMessage = array(
            'position' => $position, 
            'message' => '<div class="' . $this->classmap['warning'] . '">
                 ' . $message . '
             </div>
        ');
    }

    /**
     * Check if theres messages in the session to render 
     *
     * @param  string  $position
     * @return bool
     **/
    public function hasMessage($position = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->session->flashMessage) && !empty($position)) {
            return $this->session->flashMessage['position'] == $position ? true : false ;
        } else {
            return $this->session->flashMessage ? true : false ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Renders the flash message
     * 
     * @param  string  $position
     * @return string
     **/
    public function render($position = null)
    {   
        // -- store the message locally
        $message = $this->session->flashMessage;

        // --  check if there is in fact a flashed message
        if (empty($message))
            return;

        // -- then remove from the session
        $this->session->remove('FlashMessage');

        // -- if no position the just return the message
        if (is_null($position)) {

            return $message['message'];

        // --  else return the requested position
        } elseif ($position == $message['position']) {

            return $message['message'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this, you can extend it like you want. But this is just the gist of how it works:

```
class Messenger extends Component
{
    protected static $_messageCloseHtml = '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">&times;</a>';

    /**
     * @param array|string $messages
     */
    public static function flashError($messages)
    {
        $messages = !is_array($messages) ? [$messages] : $messages;

        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            \Phalcon\Di::getDefault()->get('flashSession')->error(self::_getBody($message));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $message
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function _getBody($message)
    {
        return self::$_messageCloseHtml . $message;
    }
}
```

For every message, you can add some HTML code to the message.

My `flashError` is for the error messages. You can add the same method code for the `warning`, `info` and `success`.

So basically you extend the (existing) `FlashSession` and when assigning the messages you call a global method which adds additional text or html to your message.